# how to get title onPageFinished() (webview)?

Tags: java, android, webview, webviewclient

i have a problem. i am using WebView Object in my project. in **MainActivity.java** code side i use *webbBrowser.setWebViewClient(new ViewBrowser());*

there is second class having name **ViewBrowser.java** this file is extended with WebViewClient.
 by using this Client service in this java file there are 2 functions Overrode 
1 - *shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)*
2 - *onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)*

in *onPageFinished()* i have used *view.getTitle();* i want to set this title to TextView on my MainActivity class. can any body help me for this.

this is my MainActivity.java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button bttnSearch;
EditText txttInput;
TextView txttView;
WebView webbBrowser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bttnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    txttInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    txttView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    webbBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.broWebView);

    webbBrowser.setWebViewClient(new ViewBrowser());
    webbBrowser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webbBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webbBrowser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webbBrowser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webbBrowser.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webbBrowser.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);

    webbBrowser.loadUrl("http:/www.google.com");

    bttnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String urlText;
    urlText = txttInput.getText().toString();

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btnGo:
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        webbBrowser.loadUrl(urlText);

        break;
    }       
}   }
```

this is my ViewBrowser.java:

```
public class QaziViewBrowser extends WebViewClient {

//private Toast txttView;

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url); 
    // i want to get Title text of the web page and set to txttView
}


}
```

Comment: you can use broadcast and send the title in intent

Comment: @Turtle i added the code and mention what i want. thanks for reply

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi can you please write some code or tell me where broadcast and intent code do. thanks for reply

Comment: is ViewBrowser.java a sub class?. i am posting my code sorry wasn't on computer

Comment: answer is posted hope it helps

Comment: thanks @SyedRazaMehdi i am working on it. hope so i will set this today .. if stuck any where i will ask you

Comment: sure any time :), happy yo help

Answer (score 1):

in you activity on create register the broadcast like this

```
registerReceiver(updateText, new IntentFilter("UPDATE_TEXT"));
```

onDestroy unregister

```
unregisterReceiver(updateText);
```

make a broadcast reciever

```
BroadcastReceiver updateText = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive()");
        // check if intent is not null and other verification if needed
         TextView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("title"));
    }
};
```

in your webview class what u have to do is fire boradcast putting the title in intent

```
        Intent intentToBroadcast = new Intent("UPDATE_TEXT");
        intentToBroadcast.putExtra(title, webview.getTitle());   
        mContext.sendBroadcast(intentToBroadcast);
```

i haven't test run this code but this is the logic that will work, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple.

In the callback onPageFinished you can get the title of the page loaded.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url); 
    // i want to get Title text of the web page and set to txttView
    String title = view.getTitle();
    // Use title where ever and which ever way you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsoup library(Download link : http://jsoup.org/).

and onPageFinished() method use below code

```
    onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
         new ContentDownloader(url).execute();
    }

    private class ContentDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        Document document;
        String url;

        public ContentDownloader(String p_url)
        {
            url = p_url;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            m_progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Wait", "Content Downloading..");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                document = Jsoup.connect(url).post();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            if(document != null) {
                m_tvTitle.setText(m_document.title());
            }

            m_progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```